# what does "important as types" mean?

Tags: reading

the scientific interest of American history centered in national character , and in the **workings** of a society destined to become vast **in which individuals were important chiefly as types.** 
[image]

```
   1. does "workings" mean labor forces?
```

like the working class? or it means like how society operates?

```
   2. individuals were important chiefly as types
```

I don't know, I think it might want to say that individuals are a crucial part, but "as types"? it provides an emphasis that those individuals are of different types?

Comment: Can you put the whole paragraph (or at least  the whole sentence) this comes from?

Comment: Up to the comma it makes no sense at all. Then it gets worse.

Comment: @user47014 i put the picture on

Comment: @OldBrixtonian i upload the whole paragraph

Comment: it is from American Character written by Henry Adams ( i don't know who he was though...)

Comment: It's an old text. He predicted the current population. Yes workings is how society operates.

Comment: @user47014 thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[type](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/type?s=t) - def. 2 - a...person regarded as a member of a class or category

It means that, for the most part, individual people were of great significance only by being members of a class or category of people larger than themselves.  It was primarily an individual person's membership in a category or class of people, that individual person being typical of the many other people comprising that category or class, that made that individual person important.

Comment: i start to catch on .  thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Harman has given you the relevant definition of "type"  but for completeness I would like to point out that "workings" in this context has meaning 2 as defined by the [Collins Online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/workings) that is:

> the way that an organization, machine, or organism operates

Collins also give the following examples of this meaning

> the workings of government

and

> I don't know anything about the workings of other departments or about the organization as a whole.

I think you should now be able to understand the sentence as a whole and see that "workings" has no relationship to "workers" oe "working classes".

Comment: thank you! now I know, I was considering workings as workers or working classes yet I also known that we always say sth like "how it works... that will work ... " etc.  well.. since it represented as a noun and I didn't really get what the writer wanted to say , that might explain where my confusion came from. again,  thank you ~ have a nice day !